# Convergent values of series containing variables approache zero

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, indeterminate-forms

Example 7 in Thomas' Calculus Early Transcendentals 14th edition p.614 demonstrates how to use Taylor series to find a limit involving an indeterminate form:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{\sin(x)} - \frac{1}{x}\right).
$$

After applying Taylor expansion to $\sin(x)$ and using some algebraic manipulation, the author came up with the following equation:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{\sin(x)} - \frac{1}{x}\right) = \lim_{x\to 0}x\frac{\frac{1}{3!} - \frac{x^2}{5!} + \frac{x^4}{7!} - ...}{1 - \frac{x^2}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{5!} -...}
$$

After that he concluded that the limit is $0$. But I'm not able to figure out why it's true because as $x$ approaches zero, how do we know the fraction on the right side of equation above approaches some constant and not infinity since both numerator and denominator are series that contain a variable (not a constant) approaching zero?

Comment: Where did you find this? The limit is not 1

Comment: Could you give a link to the paper ?

Comment: @trula and some others, it's in the book Thomas' Calculus Early Transcendentals (14th ed) p.614. Also I made one typo typing the Latex equations, it's x->0 instead of x->$\infty$ as I mentioned further in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to *define* the sine function is to let $\sin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$. The theory of power series can then be used to show that $\sin(x)$ is defined on all of $\mathbb R$ (in fact all of $\mathbb C$) and is an infinitely differentiable function satisfying the usual properties.

To compute $\lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{1}{\sin(x)}-\frac{1}{x}\right)$ using this definition note that
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{\sin(x)}-\frac{1}{x} = \frac{x-\sin(x)}{x\cdot\sin(x)} &= \frac{\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n+1}/(2n+1)!}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n+2}/(2n+1)!}\\
\end{split}
$$
Now letting $m=n-1$ we see that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n+1}/(2n+1)! = x^3f_1(x), \quad f_1(x) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^mx^{2m}}{(2m+3)!}.
$$
We also have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n+2}/(2n+1)!=x^2f_2(x), \quad f_2(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}
$$
so that
$$
\frac{1}{\sin(x)} - \frac{1}{x} = \frac{x^3f_1(x)}{x^2f_2(x)} =  x\cdot\frac{f_1(x)}{f_2(x)}.
$$
But $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are functions defined by power series which converge on all of $\mathbb R$, so they are infinitely differentiable functions. In particular they are continuous, and so $\lim_{x\to 0} f_1(x)/f_2(x) = f_1(0)/f_2(0)=\frac{1/3!}{1!} = 1/6$, and hence
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\left( \frac{1}{\sin(x)} - \frac{1}{x} \right) = \lim_{x \to 0} x\cdot\frac{f_1(x)}{f_2(x)} = \lim_{x\to 0} x\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f_1(x)}{f_2(x)} =0\cdot\frac{1}{6} = 0
$$

Comment: How can you establish that $f_{1}(x)$ and $f_{2}(x)$ converge on all of $\mathbb{R}$, using the ratio test?

Comment: For $f_1(x)$, if I write $a_m = (-1)^m x^{2m}/(2m+3)!$ then $|a_{m+1}|/|a_m| = |x|^2/(2m+4)(2m+5)< (|x|/2(m+1))^2$, hence for $m>|x|-1$, $|a_{m+1}|/|a_m|<1/4$. This if we set $k_0$ to be the unique integer with $0\leq k_0\leq |x|<k_0+1$, we have $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} |a_m| = \sum_{m<k_0} |a_m| + \sum_{m\geq k_0}|a_m| = \sum_{m <k_0}|a_m| +|a_{k_0}|\sum_{m\geq k_0} (1/4)^{m-k_0} <\infty$, and thus $\sum a_m$ converges absolutely. You can do something similar for $f_2$, or just note that $f_2(x) = 1-x^2.f_1(x)$, so if the series $f_1(x)$ converges absolutely, so must the series for $f_2(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

We shall try to see this a bit differently.

It is very easy to see that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0.$$
Suppose that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}\bigg( \frac{1}{\sin(x)}-\frac{1}{x} \bigg)$$ exists.

Then, $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0$ along with the existence of the given limit will guarantee that  $$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{\sin(x)}=\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \csc(x)$$ exists, which is absurd. This can be understood very clearly once you visualize that the functions $\csc(x)$ and $\big( \frac{1}{\sin(x)}-\frac{1}{x} \big)$ behave similarly as you go far away from $x=0.$
Indeed, from the below graph, it is very clear.

[image]

The red coloured curve is that of the function $\big( \frac{1}{\sin(x)}-\frac{1}{x} \big),$ while blue coloured is that of the function $\csc(x).$
As $x$ moves away from the origin, we have the following scene:
[image]

Hence, the given limit does not exist!

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a typo in the Latex equation, it's x->0 not x->$\infty$.  Please help to revise the answer.

Comment: Answer given by @Sine of the Time is to the point and precise.

Answer (score 0):

After the edit, the limit is:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac1x\right) $$
As suggested by the author of the book, the best way to solve the limit is using the Taylor expansion of the sine function: $\sin x =x-x^3/6+o(x^3)$.
You have:
$$ \frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac1x=\frac{x-\sin x}{x\sin x}\sim\frac{x^3}{6x^2}=\frac{x}{6} \to 0$$